# .htaccess - exclude specific URLs & directories from proxy redirect

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5.6, nuxt.js

I have Laravel set up and running fine on `https://example.com`.

I also have a Nuxt.js app set up & running fine on `http://127.0.0.1:3000`.

Now, I want to make proxy for all incoming requests for `https://example.com` to `http://127.0.0.1:3000` except -

- `https://example.com/sitemap.xml`
- `https://example.com/assets/*`
- `https://example.com/auth/*`
- `https://example.com/uploads/*`

> I want all above paths & directories use default Laravel app.

Here the .htaccess I am using for this--

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # make all request https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(assets|auth|uploads|sitemap.xml) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

> But it's making proxy for all URLs including `/sitemap.xml, /assets/*, /auth/*, /uploads/*`.

Can anyone please help.! Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you try `RewriteRule !\.(assets|auth|uploads|sitemap.xml)$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]`?

Comment: I just have tried this @Beans & this gave me a 503 error :(